# Convert Thrift object to SHA1 digest

Tags: python, hashlib

I am a newbie in Python. I try to work with server using Thrift protocol

```
struct AuthSalt {
    1: required i64 client,   /* random data */
    2: required i64 server,   /* data from previous answer */
}

struct AuthRequest {
    1: required AuthSalt bootstrap,
    2: required string who,           /* login */
    3: required string signature,     /* SHA-1: bootstrap + password + who + bootstrap. */
}

exception NotAuthorisedException {
    1: required string description
}

service Bookworm {
    AuthResponse Authenticate( 1: required AuthRequest a, 2: required string locale )
        throws ( 1: NotAuthorisedException e )
}
```

I need to create SHA1 digest using this algoritm: bootstrap + password + who + bootstrap.

To create bootstrap I use this:

```
dig = hashlib.sha1
bootstrap = AuthSalt(0, 0)
dig.update(bootstrap)
dig.update(password + who)
dig.update(bootstrap)
```

But **update** method argument type only string and I can't understand how to convert bootstrap to a string.

In C++ this code looks like:

```
SHA_CTX c;
            ::SHA1_Init(&c);
            ::SHA1_Update(&c, &bootstrap, sizeof(bootstrap));
            ::SHA1_Update(&c, password.c_str(), password.size());
            ::SHA1_Update(&c, who.c_str(), who.size());
            ::SHA1_Update(&c, &bootstrap, sizeof(bootstrap));
            ::SHA1_Final(digest, &c);
```

Can someone explain how to do it using python?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was need:

```
for x in tuple(struct.pack("Q",bootstrap.client)):
  dig.update(x)
```

Convert i64 into 8 bytes and update hash with every byte

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that `str(bootstrap)` instead of `bootstrap` should work.

Comment: No, this is not correct. Please, look carefully on C++ code. As I understand str(bootstrap) - this is string representaion of object, but I need string representation of two bytes from bootstrap.
Bootstrap is structure (64-bit signed integer).
str(bootstrap.client) + str(bootstrap.server) - also not correct.